# How to change the url string with inputs from the user in SwiftUI

Tags: json, api, swiftui, state, picker

i am making this app that uses jikan API to show a list of animes, so in the url there is an option to change stuff like the type - anime, manga, etc and the subtype - upcoming, tv, movie, etc, the API is working working fine and is fetching details but now I want to show two pickers in a form view preferably to allow the user to select type and subtype thus I have used @State properties for the picker but it's not updating the list when I run the app and select a different value from the picker

here is the code -

```
import SwiftUI


struct Response: Codable{
    var top: [Result]
    
}

struct Result: Codable {
    
    var mal_id: Int
    var rank: Int
    var title: String
    var type: String
    var start_date: String?
    var image_url: String
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var str2 = ""
   @State private var str3 = ""
    
    func loadData() {

         str3 = String("/\(subtype[subTypeSelection])")
        
         str2 = String("\(type[typeSelection])/")
        
        let str1 = "https://api.jikan.moe/v3/top/"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: str1 + str2 + "\(1)" + str3) else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
                    // we have good data – go back to the main thread
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        // update our UI
                        self.top = decodedResponse.top
                    }
                    // everything is good, so we can exit
                    return
                }
            }
            // if we're still here it means there was a problem
            print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
        }.resume()
    }

     var type = ["anime", "manga", "people", "characters"]
     var subtype = ["airing", "upcoming", "tv", "movie", "ova", "special"]
    
    
    @State private var page = 1
    @State private var typeSelection = 0
    @State private var subTypeSelection = 2
   
    @State private var top = [Result]()
    var body: some View {
//        ScrollView {
        VStack {
       
            Picker("Your  Selection", selection: $subTypeSelection) {
                
                ForEach(0 ..< 6) {
                    somehting in
                    Text("\(subtype[somehting])")
                }
            }
                Picker("Your  Selection", selection: $typeSelection) {
                    
                    ForEach(0 ..< 4) {
                        somehting in
                        Text("\(type[somehting])")
                    }
                }
        }
        
//        .onAppear(perform: {
//            loadData()
//        })
            List(top, id: \.mal_id) { item in
                
                HStack {
                    AsyncImage(url: URL(string: item.image_url)!,
                                   placeholder: { Text("Loading ...") },
                                   image: { Image(uiImage: $0).resizable() })
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
//                        .frame(idealHeight: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 10 * 10 )
                        
                        .clipShape(Capsule())
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text(item.title)
                                    .font(.headline)
                                Text(String("\(item.rank)"))
                                    .font(.headline)
                                Text(item.type)
                                    .font(.headline)
                                Text(item.start_date ?? "")
                                                .font(.headline)
                                
                    }
                }
                    }
                      // }
            .onAppear(perform: loadData)
       
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: loadData is only being called in `onAppear` as far as I can see, where do you expect any updates to be performed?

Comment: I want the url string to be updated as soon as the user selects a different item from the picker view which in turn then changes the value of str2 and str3 so my url has changed and it should load different data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try to use "onChange" on each picker:

```
VStack {
    Picker("Your subtype Selection", selection: $subTypeSelection) {
        ForEach(0 ..< 6) { somehting in
            Text("\(subtype[somehting])").tag(somehting)
        }
    }.onChange(of: subTypeSelection) { value in
        loadData()
    }
    Picker("Your type Selection", selection: $typeSelection) {
        ForEach(0 ..< 4) { somehting in
            Text("\(type[somehting])").tag(somehting)
        }
    }.onChange(of: typeSelection) { value in
        loadData()
    }
}
```

It's not very efficient, but I'm sure you will find a better way to re-load the data.